# Why doesn't LTspice take the default model parameters for voltage controlled switch?

Tags: ltspice, simulation

In the below example circuit, if I try to use the default model of voltage controlled switch, why does the simulation throw an error?

[image]

If I customise the model parameters using .MODEL command, it works fine.

Why can't the tool take the default values? I defined Gmin just in case that is the only unknown to the tool!

[image]

Comment: The name of the switch needs to be changed (just as R needs a number and a value). See https://www.analog.com/en/resources/technical-articles/ltspiceiv-voltage-controlled-switches.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SW` device requires a `.model` statement, even if you want all default parameter values.  Therefore, you simply need to add a `.model SW SW` SPICE directive on the schematic if you want to use the default parameters along with the default symbol name.

[image]

Diodes, BJTs, and MOSFETs require this too, but for those LTspice will automatically add SPICE directives `.model D D`, `.model NPN NPN`, `.model NMOS NMOS`, etc. into your netlist behind the scenes whenever one of those symbols are used.  It does not do this for switches, so you have to explicitly do it as shown above.